# Как вывести список категорий на Опенкарт?

Tags: php, opencart3.x

Нужно вывести список категорий на Опенкарт 3.0 В Опенкарте уже имеются контроллер (catalog/controller/product/category.php) и модель(catalog/model/catalog/product.php),которые относятся к категориям.Мне нужно в этих файлах создавать отдельные методы в том файле или создавать как отдльный модуль или в существующих методах вносить изменения,какие?

Comment: В основном все правят файлы опенкарта. Но ты можешь написать свой ocmod

Comment: а есть  хоть нормальная документация, ну или какие нибудь уроки по изменения функционала Опенкарта?Потому что  видел, не совсем помогло.Мне проще с нуля написать выборку,но о когда это в Опенкарте :\

Comment: Документации там не надо как таковой.  Там простейшее MVC. Главное понять принцип

Comment: ну не скажите, я понимаю принци MVC и создавал без проблем выборку используя данный паттерн, но то что в Опенкарте написано -ад,на фреймворках и то понятнее. К тому же словие усложнилось,нужно использовать API ия  вот умаю использовать API Опенкарта, только пока что не придумал как.